# load 3d model in qt using librviz

Tags: ros, librviz, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i am trying to create a qt gui that display a 3d model from a 3d model file. (e.g .dae .stl)
is there anyway i could do it with librviz?

librviz_tutorial with the grid display provides something similar to what i need, but i have no idea how i could modify the code.
are there any examples or tutorials where i could refer to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187225/load-3d-model-in-qt-using-librviz/) by [qing](https://answers.ros.org/users/19798/qing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

librviz isn't really designed to be a model viewer; it's designed as a robotics data visualizer.

In theory, you could visualize a model by publishing it as a Marker, or by creating a URDF with your model and visualizing that, but both of those involve some additional overhead in addition to using the rviz qt widget.

A quick google search turns up a tutorial on [Loading a 3D model in Qt](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Loading-a-3D-Model), which is much closer to what you're asking for.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1